# How to refresh a single div on <a> click?

Tags: java, jquery

I have displayed some dynamic data on one div but untill I refresh the page the data of that div doesn't refreshes.
And I have one `<a>` tag that is used as add to cart.
I have called one function on a onclick.
I want to refresh div after click on `<a>` tag.
But how to do that I don;t know.
Any idea ??

My Script Code That Calls when `<a>` onclick :

```
function addProductById(pId,pMqty){
            $.getJSON("addtocart?pid=" + pId + "&minqty="+ pMqty +"&rand=" + Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1), function(json) {
                alert(json.msg);                
            });
        }
```

Here `addtocart` is `servlet`.

div that I want to refresh on `<a>` click :

```
        <div style="float: right;margin-top: 30px;margin-right: -19px;" id="cartcounter">
        <%
        int cart_item=0;
            try
            {
                ShoppingCart cart = (ShoppingCart)session.getAttribute("shop");
                cart_item = cart.getSize(); 
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("No Item In Cart");
            }           
        %>
        <%= cart_item %>
    </div>
```

`<a>` :

```
<a href="#" onclick="addProductById(<%= id %>,<%= minqty %>)">
```

Comment: While setting data, first clear your div.

Comment: it may be use full...

how to refresh a single <div>


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667884/how-do-i-refresh-the-contents-of-a-single-div?rq=1

Comment: Get div and first set its html to empty as:
document.getElementById("ponies").innerHTML = "";
Then assign data from your ajax response:
document.getElementById("ponies").innerHTML = your ajax-data;

Comment: @ParkashKumar - clear means ??

Comment: Clear means empty. :p

Comment: Oh I see. I am trying as per you told me in comment where I have to clear div then fill up new data.

Comment: @ParkashKumar - I have tried `document.getElementById("cartcounter").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('cartcounter').innerHTML = "<% ShoppingCart cartd = (ShoppingCart)session.getAttribute("shop");%><%=cartd.getSize()%>";` but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this.**

```
function addProductById(pId,pMqty){
        $.getJSON("addtocart?pid=" + pId + "&minqty="+ pMqty +"&rand=" + Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1), function(json) {

            $("#YourDivID").html("your html which you want to show !!!");

            //Or you can use jquery load to refresh your div dynamically 

           $("#YourDivID").load("/HelloWorld/GetAwesomePartialView");

            alert(json.msg);   


        });
    }
```

**hope this will help you ..**

Comment: In .load method what should I have to take as an argument ?

Comment: from your code i had determine your are using asp.net mvc with aspx view engine In this case you should bind your div with some partial view . And in above code in .Load you have pass  .lod("yourControllerName/YourPartialView") which will return your some dynamic data. Hope this helps you .

Comment: No no no sir ji, I am using Java(JSP). Not a asp.net.

Comment: Ohh ohh sorry !!! my illusion !! but jquery load will work in your case too . look at this example . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987391/load-a-jsp-page-using-ajax-load-method

Comment: I have also tried `$("#cartcounter").load("#cartcounter");` but it's not working. in load(argument) what I will I have take that I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Put this outside the script tag:

```
<% ShoppingCart cartd = (ShoppingCart)session.getAttribute("shop");%>
```

Then in your script tag's function,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function(){
    document.getElementById("cartcounter").innerHTML = "";
    var cartSize = '<%=cartd.getSize() %>';
    document.getElementById('cartcounter').innerHTML = cartSize;
}  
</script>
```

Comment: when that function will be called ? Can i put this function data in my above ajax function ?

Comment: Where you were calling first?

Comment: I have written your function code in my `addproducybyId()` function. But it's not working.

Comment: And when is your addproducybyId() called?

Comment: on `<a> onclick` , I have described it in my question at last.

Comment: Are you getting JSON data and setting div on same method.

Comment: Yes I am using `JSON` to pass data to `addtocart` servlet and in div `cartcounter` I am getting simple session data which I have inserted in `addtocart` servlet.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42579/discussion-between-parkash-kumar-and-java-curious-)

Comment: Technique of my answer is useful, when you have already written response for you jsp. Get those request parameters (data) and then show on div. For the case when you want to call a runtime method to server, you need AJAX approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .load(url) or .html() method for refreshing the div.

```
$('#cartcounter').load("addtocart?pid=" + pId + "&minqty="+ pMqty +"&rand=" + Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1));
```

use `response.getWriter().write(cart_item)` and return null in your addtocart servlet. 
your div content will be updated.

Comment: means I have to change whole function ? and have to write like that ??

Comment: right. have a try it will work. I have implemented the same thing many time in application when I just need to update the content of a particular segment in my webpage

Comment: but what you telling me about `response.write (cart_item)` that I don't understand.

Comment: I mean whatever content with which you want to update your div should be set in response. Also, if your servlet use forward/redirect to another view then that whole view will be displayed in the div.

Comment: No I haven't use `forward.redierct` in my `addtocart` servlet, I am just inserting product id in session shop in that `addtocart` servlet using `JSON`.

Comment: So now your cart size is updated.. right.. now use response.getWriter().write(cartSize); return null;
Your div content will be updated.

Comment: here `cartSize` means `cart.getSize()` or other ?

Comment: sure. Please let me know in case you find any issue.

Comment: Ok I ll inform you if I ll face any issue, and thank you so much.

Comment: No, It's not working Properly. Ana cart is also not updated using this snippet.

Comment: Means are you asking me to send mu code or you ll send me code ?

Comment: Ok, if possible then only otherwise leave it. If you have time then it ll be fine.